# Juntar fecha y hora en una variable

Tags: java, date

Quisiera saber cómo se puede juntar una fecha y una hora entregada por un usuario en una sola variable de tipo `Date`

```
System.out.println("Ingrese fecha desde la cual se desea programar los pedidos para su producción");

    SimpleDateFormat sdfg = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String fe=lector.readLine();
    Date fechaProg=sdfg.parse(fe); 

    System.out.println("Ingrese hora desde la cual se desea programar los pedidos para su producción");
    SimpleDateFormat hora=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String h=lector.readLine();
    Date horaProg=hora.parse(h);


    SimpleDateFormat fechaHora= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    Date fh;
    fh = fechaHora.parse(h+fe);// creo que el problema esta aqui pero no se como arreglarlo
    cxn.EnviarProgProd(fh);
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu formato contiene un espacio entre la fecha y la hora:

```
"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
           ^ aquí
```

Cuando mandas la cadena a procesar, no tiene ese espacio:

```
fechaHora.parse(h+fe);
```

Agrega el espacio manualmente:

```
fechaHora.parse(h+" "+fe);
```

Además, considera que estás usando distintos formatos para la hora:

```
//cuando capturas la hora, lo haces con HH
SimpleDateFormat hora=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
//...
//cuando quieres la fecha y la hora, la hora tiene formato con hh
SimpleDateFormat fechaHora= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

prueba con:

```
 fh = fechaHora.parse(h+" "+fe);
```

Comment: Intenta ser más descriptivo, como @Luiggi Mendoza J para saber en que falló, y no sea mágia para el OP